# Ревью Архитектуры приложения

Tags: c#, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования, инспекция-кода

Есть решение разбитое на следующие *слои*: `DAO`, `DAL`, `Services` `Gui` где,

- `DAO` - здесь хранятся классы описывающие доменнные модели;
- `DAL` - Generic Repository и его реализация;
- `Services` - здесь у меня методы по типу следующего: `IEnumerable<Entity> GetEntities()`;
- `Gui` - клиентская часть

предвижу сразу вопрос чем Services отличается от Repository, в репозитории у меня базовые методы *CRUD*:

```
void Create(Entity entity);
void Update(Entity entity);
void Delete(Entity entity);
IQueryable<Entity> Table {get;}
```

в `Services` же у меня строются более сложные запросы: соединения, группировка например:

```
var _orders = получаем данные;
var _histories = получаем данные;
var orders = _orders.Join(_histories, o=>o.Id, h=>h.OrderId,(o,h)=>new OrderView
                    {
                        //Формируем необходимое представление
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

ну и т.п.

зависимости между проектами следующие:

- `DAO` подключен в качестве `reference` в `DAL, Services, Gui`
- `DAL` подключен в качестве `reference` в `Services, Gui`
- `Services` подключен в качестве `reference` в `Gui`

Хочу проект сделать так что бы дальнейшая поддержка причиняла как можно меньше проблем.

Правильно ли я поступил разбив проект на более мелкие части, или я сделал так зря и необходимо слить все в один проект а разделение сделать на уровне директорий внутри решения и `namespace`.

Буду премного благодарен за ссылки на литературу которую стоит почитать что бы прояснить для себя как правильно строить *каркас* приложения

Comment: Сильвер буллета в вопросе проектирвоания архитектуры проекта не существует.

Comment: @Bezarius ну теоретически данное выражение можно использовать везде: *Серебрянной пули для {0} не существует*. :) просто собрался делать глобальный рефакторинг и решил спросить у экспертов не заложил ли я себе мины замедленного действия

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть самые разные способы проектирования приложения. Как я вижу вы пытаетесь использовать [DDD](http://habrahabr.ru/post/61524/). Этот паттрен достаточно универсален, но не является сильвербуллетом, а так же имеет очень много вариаций реализации, например [CQRS+ES](http://habrahabr.ru/post/146429/) или [DDD+Onion](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) которые имеют свои назначения, а вместе с ним свои плюсы и минусы.

По мимо DDD и его вариаций, существуют такие архитектурные паттерны как [EDA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0), [SOA](http://www.finecosoft.ru/soa), [NLayer](http://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/NLayer-Architecture) и другие.

Что бы поддержка не причиняла больших проблем, нужно сначала выбрать правильную архитектуру, а это вопрос не только правильного выбора паттерна, но языка, стека технологий и многого другого. Сам же выбор зависит от решаемой задачи и различных условий.

Comment: а можете сказать по поводу правильности/корректности реализации *DDD*?! разработку веду с использованием стека технологий *.Net*. использую orm *Entity Framework*, также использую *Autofac* в качестве IoC контейнера

Comment: спасибо за ответ и ссылки в нем. лишний раз убедился в необходимости приобретения [Шаблоны корпоративных приложений](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4884925/), вот только озон рекомендует еще и [Шаблоны реализации корпоративных приложений](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3938906/), на что лучше обратить внимание?! или надо брать обе?

Comment: @Bald56rus почитайте Фаулера, думаю вам хватит. Да и архитектором не стать после прочтения пары книг :)

Answer (score 1):

Был у меня опыт разработки именно при такой архитектуре, только за место Entity Framework использовался NHibernate. Ну и был еще один дополнительный слой абстракции для веб сервисов. То бишь было параллельно несколько веб сервисов, которые пользовались фунциями из слоя Services.

В целом код получался весьма читабельным и понятным. Но вместе с этим при реализации функции в GUI приходилось протягивать эту функцию через все слои это со временем начинало бесить. Получалось как-то слишком много лишнего кода который приходилось писать лишь из-за всех этих слоёв. Дебаг так же происходил чуть медленнее. Были некоторые трудности с определением того куда стоит засунуть функцию, в DAL или Services. В целом считаю данную архитектуру весьма адекватной для решения многих задач. Она предлагает высокую степень гибкости и читабельности, но может стать очень громоздкой. Что бы избавиться от громоздкозти этого монолита мне кажется, можно было бы начать отщипывать от монолита микросервисы.