# Помогите допонять со слоями dao и service

Tags: java, service, dao

Допустим, есть у меня сущности **user**,**result**,**courses**.
Для них, соответственно, напишу дао. В **userdao** все возможные запросы к **usery**, в **resultdao** все возможные запросы к **result** и также с **courses**.
Далее, я создаю слой сервисов я так понимаю, что в него будет входить **student, teacher, admin** (т.е. те, кто будут в роли пользователей моего приложения)
И в сервисе **studentservice** я соберу весь необходимый функционал для него с помощью разных **дао** и так для остальных пользователей.
Я правильно понял суть этих слоёв?
Заранее большое спасибо за ответ!

Comment: посмотрите как пытаюсь строить подобную [архитектуру](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/473693/179270) я.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DAO (Data Access Objects) - шаблон проектирования, определяющий механизм доступа к данным ([ссылка на вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Access_Object)). Грубо говоря, в классах дао (UserDao итд) вы должны организовать методы получения определенных объектов или коллекций этих объектов, а также методы для работы с этими объектами (CRUD-операции). В целом, вы это и описываете в вопросе..

Сервисы - это уже более высокоуровневые классы. В них описывается бизнес-логика. То есть, поведение объектов при более высокоуровневых операциях (например, student просто начинает course, а в случае teacher курс также делается активным (это пример возможного сценария)).

Для вашего случая я поступил несколько иначе:

1. Сделал бы абстракцию User(interface/abstract class) и унаследовал всех остальных пользователей от него.
2. Реализовал бы Service и везде в нем работал бы с абстракным User`ом.
3. При необходимости расширил бы сервис для специфики конкретных пользователей.

Answer (score 1):

Можете ваши UserDAO, ResultDAO и CoursesDAO орагнизовать как интерфейсы.
Далее уже их реализуешь через классы например  UserDAOImpl ResultDAOImpl CoursesDAOImpl. 
Далее также делаешь с Servcie слоем. 
Пишешь интерфейсы, реализуешь их. И в их реализациях уже добавляешь соответсвующую переменную твоего интерфейса ДАО.
Дергая потом эту переменную будешь и дергать свои методы дао, которые тебе будут нужны для логики твоего приложения.